# Command failed: wmic process after updating npm in Express app in my code

Tags: node.js, wmic

[image: image on code error]

hello pls I have a problem on my code.
nodemon is installed. It is working for once. But whenever I refresh the file, the error "wmic process command failed" occurs
pls I need help

Comment: have you tried restarting the entire setup?

Comment: yes i have done so

Comment: the ```reference error : f is not found``` does it occur every time you refresh?

Comment: No i dont get that error. i always get the error "UnhandlePromiseRejectionWarning: Error: CommandFailed: wmic process..." from this error down, that i get. each time i refresh.

Comment: This issue seems to be affecting windows users with the latest version of nodemon. Try downgrading nodemon to version 2.0.7 and make sure you have the latest version of node installed. cheers

Comment: Can you give me the code for downgrading nodemon?

Comment: ```npm install -g nodemon@2.0.7```